# What programming language is used to IMPLEMENT google algorithm?

Tags: database, programming-languages

- It is known that google has best searching & indexing algorithm.
- The also have good relevancy.
- They are also quicker in getting down the latest results.

All that's fine.

What programming language (c, c++, java, etc...) & database (oracle, MySQL, etc...) have they used in achieving this (since they have to manipulate with volume of data quickly and effectively)?.

Though I'm not looking for their in-depth architecture (if in case violates their company policies) an overview of all such things could be useful.

Anybody please add you valuable suggestions and insight on this?

Comment: the language used is irrelevant, there's a technology overview http://www.google.com/corporate/tech.html and more publications than you can read http://research.google.com/pubs/papers.html

Comment: Good answers. Also great to hear google have highly effective in-house database management system. If they leverage this, it means they also have an other business in hand ;)

Comment: Programming languages are not used in algorithm design. They are used in algorithm implementation. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I have rephrased my question accordingly. But the intention was to know only the implementation

Comment: So you're now asking two questions: programming languages used by Google and an overview of their architecture, or whatever else you mean by 'all such things', which again isn't clear, and in any case should have been a separate question, probably unanswerable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google internally use C++, Java and Python. See [Rhino on Rails](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/06/rhino-on-rails.html):

> One of the (hundreds of) cool things
>   about working for Google is that they
>   let teams experiment, as long as it's
>   done within certain broad and
>   well-defined boundaries. One of the
>   fences in this big playground is your
>   choice of programming language. You
>   have to play inside the fence defined
>   by C++, Java, Python, and JavaScript.

Google's search algorithm is essentially [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), which stems from functional programming techniques, implemented in C++.

Google has its own storage mechanism for this called the [Google File System](http://research.google.com/archive/gfs.html).

Answer (score 5):

Mainly [pigeons](http://www.google.com/technology/pigeonrank.html):

> PigeonRank's success relies primarily on the superior trainability of the domestic pigeon (Columba livia) and its unique capacity to recognize objects regardless of spatial orientation. The common gray pigeon can easily distinguish among items displaying only the minutest differences, an ability that enables it to select relevant web sites from among thousands of similar pages.

Comment: "Google uses only low-cost, off-the-street pigeons for its clusters."

Answer (score 3):

Relevance of search results is governed by quality of information retrieval algorithms they use, not the programming language.

But C++ is what most of their backend code is written in (for most services).

They don't use any off-the-shelf RDBMS products for data storage. All of that is written in-house.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out, the [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html).

Comment: A data structure is a programming language?

Comment: I think you can derive the answers from studying their published work, and you'd learn more than being told.  After all, what does the original poster do when they're told the language(s) that Google use?  Learn it so they too can implement those kind of algorithms?